# .tgz file – tar: Unrecognized archive format

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion, tar, gzip, mongodb

I'm trying to install a [10gen build of MongoDB](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/#installing-from-10gen-builds) on my local Mac running Mountain Lion (10.8.3):

I fetch it with `curl` at:

```
curl http://downloads.mongodb.org/osx/mongodb-osx-x86_64-2.4.tgz > mongodb.tgz
```

But I can't extract the build:

**Attempt 1:**

```
$ tar -zxvf mongodb.tgz

tar: Unrecognized archive format
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors.
```

**Attempt 2:**

```
$ gunzip mongodb.tgz

gzip: mongodb.tgz: not in gzip format
```

**Attempt 3:**

```
$ unzip mongodb.tgz

Archive:  mongodb.tgz
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of mongodb.tgz or
        mongodb.tgz.zip, and cannot find mongodb.tgz.ZIP, period.
```

**Double Clicking:**
If I double click the tgz file in the finder, it creates a new file `mongodb.tgz 2.cpgz`

---

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here? I tried various builds and they all reproduce this issue:

```
http://downloads.mongodb.org/osx/mongodb-osx-x86_64-2.4.tgz > mongodb.tgz
http://downloads.mongodb.org/osx/mongodb-osx-x86_64-2.3.tgz > mongodb.tgz
http://downloads.mongodb.org/osx/mongodb-osx-x86_32-2.4.tgz > mongodb.tgz
http://downloads.mongodb.org/osx/mongodb-osx-x86_32-2.3.tgz > mongodb.tgz
```

Comment: do a "file mongodb.tgz" to identify the content type...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you are trying to gunzip/untar not the archive file but the error page:

```
<html>
<head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head>
<body>
<h1>403 Forbidden</h1>
<ul>
<li>Code: AccessDenied</li>
<li>Message: Access Denied</li>
</ul>
<hr/>
</body>
</html>
```

try this link http://fastdl.mongodb.org/osx/mongodb-osx-x86_64-2.4.0.tgz

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think to open that link in a browser. I'm reporting it to 10gen so they can fix the link. Cheers mate :)

Answer (score 2):

Apologies, try http://fastdl.mongodb.org/osx/mongodb-osx-x86_64-2.4.0.tgz
The download URL changed with the release which we'll fix in the docs.

Comment: What are you apologizing for?  Why are you repeating the link that Alex already gave?

Comment: Because I own the docs website where this was in error?  We recently changed to version the MongoDB documentation, as a sideeffect instead of including the release (2.4.0) we were including the version (2.4) in these URLs which are updated when we do a new release.

Comment: (1) No error, but it might have been nice to (_briefly_) state your affiliation/association in your answer, rather than forcing us to open your user page.  (2) Why are you repeating the link that [Alex P.](http://superuser.com/users/192715/alex-p) already gave in [his answer](http://superuser.com/a/568531/150988), which he posted more than an hour before you posted yours?

Comment: @Scott. It is nice to get an _official_ answer, where available.

Comment: @TRiG: (1) Wow!  If you had just waited another four days, you could have observed the four-year anniversary of this answer.  Is this four-year-old information still valid/useful?  (2) Thanks, but I understood the significance of @epc’s comment that he is the owner of the MongoDB docs website; i.e., that his answer represented an “*official*” one.  (3) After four years, ***the answer*** still doesn’t include any claim to authority by association.

Comment: (Cont’d) …  And, while we at [SE] believe in the rules of [Be Nice](/help/be-nice) and [assume good intentions/good faith](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/240839/195817), we also prefer statements that are supported by evidence. What evidence is there that this is an official answer? What evidence is there that epc is who he says he is? He claims it in his Super User profile, but not his profile on Stack Overflow or Stack Exchange, or his personal home page. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  Furthermore, this is the only answer he has ever posted on Super User.  In fact, he created his Super User account just to post this answer, and, after posting the follow-up comment, he has never logged in again.  These are red flags.  I’m not calling him a liar, just questioning the authenticity of his claims.